# RegEx to extract block from twig template

Tags: php, regex, twig

In PHP, I want to extract the text included in a twig block and thought that regex would be the most efficient.

Let's say I have a file "index.twig" with this content:

```
{% block content %}
Content of the page...
{% endblock %}
```

This code works perfectly fine:

```
$input = file_get_contents("index.twig"); 
preg_match_all('/\{%\s*block\s*content\s*\%}([^\%}]*)\{%\s*endblock\s*\%}/', $input, $output);
```

$output will contain the expected result.

However, if the input file is something like:

```
{% block content %}
{{ a_tag }}
Content of the page...
{% endblock %}
```

In this case, the closing }} breaks the regex and $output is empty.

Any clue for the correct regex?

Another solution to extract the content of the block?

I would like to get:

```
{{ a_tag }}
Content of the page...
```

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: @DarkBee I'm building a very lightweight framework, for personal projects and pedagogy

Comment: Looks strange to me to extract twig templates that all. Anyway just `/{% block content %}(.+){% endblock %}/s` as seen [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KKnsCIUskjdVuLOj)

Comment: Like this? `^{%.*%}\R((?:(?!{%.*?%}$).*\R)*){%.*%}$` https://regex101.com/r/LtUCiy/1

Comment: Or use `{%\h*block\h*content\h*%}\R((?:(?!{%\h*endblock\h*%}).*\R)*){%\h*endblock\h*%}` https://regex101.com/r/jFKi84/1

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee the code and the link are very helpful. For the purpose of doing that, I am trying to have some inheritance in my templates

Comment: Thanks @the-fourth-bird that works very well and another great link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[^\%}]*` means that you match any character except the listed using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), which in this case are `%` (which you don't have to escape) and `}`.

Using that approach, you can not match `{{ a_tag }}` between the blocks.

---

One way to get the values is to match the starting code for the block until the first occurrence of the end block. In between you match all the lines that do not start with the endblock pattern.

Instead of using `\s`, you could use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace char and `\R` to match any unicode newline sequence.

```
{%\h*block\h*content\h*%}\R((?:(?!{%\h*endblock\h*%}).*\R)*){%\h*endblock\h*%}
```

The pattern will match:

- `{%\h*block\h*content\h*%}\R` Match the block content part and a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:(?!{%\h*endblock\h*%}).*\R)*` Match the whole line and a newline if the line does not start with the endblock pattern
- `)` Close group 1
- `{%\h*endblock\h*%}` Match the endblock part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFKi84/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace everything that matches a twig tag with and empty string. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$x = <<<EOT
{% block content %}
  {{ a_tag }}
  Content of the page...
{% endblock %}
EOT;

$x = preg_replace(['/\{%[^\{\}]*%\}\n*/m', '/\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}\n*/m'], '', $x);
$y = preg_replace('/\{%[^\{\}]*%\}\n*/m', '', $x);
print $x;
print PHP_EOL;
print $y;
```

Comment: Thi is almost it! Now something returns, but without the twig var. The things is that I would like to keep {{ a_tag}} in the output

Comment: That's not what you originally had in your question. That is still possible. Just remove the second pattern from the array. I have edited the answer to show that.

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is useless because there are no `^` or `$` metacharacters in the patterns.  You are also doing too much unnecessary escaping in your patterns.  Only checking for `\n` will mean that your solution will not hold up on different operating systems (like ones that use `\r`). Please only post regex patterns that you understand so that you don't misinform researchers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I am using from the comments:

```
{%\h*block\h*content\h*%}\R((?:(?!{%\h*endblock\h*%}).*\R)*){%\h*endblock\h*%}
```

Here are 2 useful links to setup regex patterns:

- https://www.debuggex.com/r/KKnsCIUskjdVuLOj
- https://regex101.com/r/jFKi84/1